# Copy last cell range with data

Tags: vba, excel

I can't get the last section of my code to read the last cells in columns F through L with data. There will be blank cells above them. Then paste to the next available line in destination.

`Sub addddddddddddddd()
'
' addddddddddddddd Macro
'
Dim LR As Long, LC As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant, wb As Workbook
Dir "C:\User\keym\Desktop\Timecards"
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (.), .", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)`

```
wb.Activate
Range("D1").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Vacation-Sick-Summary.xls").Activate
Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

wb.Activate
Range("F3:L3").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Vacation-Sick-Summary.xls").Activate
Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
For Each C In Selection
    If C.Value = "" Then C.Value = "-"
    C.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Next C


wb.Activate
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row              '?
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column    '?
Selection.Copy
wb.Close
Windows("Vacation-Sick-Summary.xls").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
For Each C In Selection
    If C.Value = "" Then C.Value = "-"
    C.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Next C
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).Select
```

or whichever column you require.

In your last section of your code: check the `Selection` your are copying; check also that you mean to  test for the last row of data in col A and for the last column of data along row 1.

Comment: That works great! How do i get it to copy also the 6 cells to the right?

Comment: Mike - which six cells and from where to where?

Comment: The six cells to the right of the selection. I have figured it out.  Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 7).Copy                                  Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK well done.  If this answers your Q perhaps you would accept the answer which will also close-off this thread.